# How to include SqlParameter Values in SqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, error-handling

I inherited an ASP.Net system that seems to break quite often.  It runs on top of Sql Server 2008r2.  There's a handy 'Exceptions' Page that spits out all the exception data for unhandled exceptions.

More often than not, these are `SqlExceptions`, and of these, frequently the issue is a foreign key constraint error, but I can never tell from the saved data what the value of the missing FK reference was.  This makes it very difficult to debug.

Is there a way to tell either ASP.Net/IIS or SQL Server to include the passed parameter values in `SqlException.Data`?

Comment: On SqlException your code goes into catch block and can not you put paramertes into message text of exception and log it then. Take a look in example area https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, the current exception handling is happening behind the scenes.  I could do this for most of my future code, but updating all the current code would be a very large job.  Besides that, there is still some code that is executed completely invisible to me--like the current issue I'm looking at--so this solution won't work for me.  :-/

Comment: Do you have access to the sql database (i.e. could you run SQL Profiler on the db)?

Comment: I do.  I've never used Profiler before, though.